# Virtualenv in windows, activates another env in a completely different directory

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I´m using virtualenv for windows, I have the following structure

Root/
  env/
    scripts/
      activate

When I execute from root 'env\scripts\activate' it seems another environment from a completely different directory is being activated, and not the one present in the current directory, I check this by running 'pip list'

any clues? thanks

Comment: What options did you use when creating the environment?